# Exist strictly increasing $f \colon \omega _1 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory, real-numbers, ordinals

Does there exist a strictly increasing injective function $f \colon \omega _1 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, where $\omega _1$ denotes the first uncountable ordinal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If so, there is some rational between $f(\alpha)$ and $f(\alpha+1)$
for each $\alpha\in\omega_1$, and so uncountably many rationals, as these
rationals must be distinct.